# What are some practical uses of SQLite3's reverse binary collation?

Tags: database, sqlite

An associate asked about something Owens wrote in The Definitive Guide to SQLite, 2nd ed, p101, regarding collation types: "reverse is more for testing (and perhaps illustration) than anything else."

Is this arguably valid for SQLite's implementation as a dbms? Does a reverse binary collation have practical use? Does SQLite's reverse/binary collation affect query performance, perhaps, for example, when using ORDER BY?

Comment: Perhaps this is no longer for SQLite3, as the current documentation doesn't mention reverse. http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation

Comment: You can use the reverse collation type during table creation, but not as a WHERE modifier nor when creating an index. Hmmm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not have a `reverse` collation.

Apparently, there is a confusion between the [`rtrim` collation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation) (which ignores trailing space characters) and the `reverse_unordered_selects` pragma.

The latter is useful for testing; [its documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_reverse_unordered_selects) says:

> **PRAGMA reverse_unordered_selects =** *boolean*;
>
> When enabled, this PRAGMA causes SELECT statements without an ORDER BY clause to emit their results in the reverse order of what they normally would. This can help debug applications that are making invalid assumptions about the result order.
>
> SQLite makes no guarantees about the order of results if a SELECT omits the ORDER BY clause. Even so, the order of results does not change from one run to the next, and so many applications mistakenly come to depend on the arbitrary output order whatever that order happens to be. However, sometimes new versions of SQLite will contain optimizer enhancements that will cause the output order of queries without ORDER BY clauses to shift. When that happens, applications that depend on a certain output order might malfunction. By running the application multiple times with this pragma both disabled and enabled, cases where the application makes faulty assumptions about output order can be identified and fixed early, reducing problems that might be caused by linking against a different version of SQLite.